# Im making a discord bot that says hi when someone says hello but it also says hi when someone uses it in a word like "tHIng. How do i prevent that?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So whenever someone says hi in a word (eg: thing) it replies with hi. How do I make it so that it only replies with hi if its by itself? (Also I'm 14 and a beginner so please don't make it overly complicated). just so you know it runs fine and whenever someone says hello it replies but I don't want it to say hello when the word hi is in a word or sentence

Here is my code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    greetings = ["hello" , "hi" , "hey" , "wassup" , "sup" , "yo"]

    if any(word in message.content.lower()for word in greetings):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return
    
    
    await message.channel.send("Hello there, " + str(message.author))
    print("Reply to hello command has been executed")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if any(word in message.content.lower().split() for word in greetings):
    if message.author == client.user: return
```

I added `split` method so if they type "hi greetings bot", bot will check after splitting it to `["hi", "greetings", "bot"]`. And when type "i wanna say something", our list will be `["i", "wanna", "say", "something"]` an bot won'r answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly and you want the bot to answer only if the message is "hi" but no if it is "hi mark" then you need to check if the message is just that.

```py
if any(message.content.lower().strip() == word for word in greetings):
    ...
```

Strip just removes spaces at the beginning and end of the string.

If what you want is to check if the greeting is inside the sentence but not a part of a specific word then @Welylyn already answered that.

I hope this helps, I'm also learning